# Angular 9: i18n in TypeScript

Tags: angular, angular-material, internationalization, angular9

I studied the new i18n feature in Angular 9. https://angular.io/guide/i18n

How to translate text in TypeScript, e.g. SnackBar messages?

Comment: Why down vote without comment?

Comment: I think you are looking for `$localize`. If I remember correctly once the angular i18n-setup was successfully done, `$localize` should be globally available and you can use it as `$localize\`MY_STRING_TO_BE_TRANSLATED\``. Again, I have not digged into angular's i18n implementation yet, so take it with caution. Overall I suggest `ngx-translate` over the solution provided by angular _right now_.

Comment: @NoobieNoob What's wrong with Muhammet's answer below?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Check this blog https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/12/10/angular-localize/

#### UPDATE FOR 2022

From Offical Doc: https://angular.io/api/localize

```
@Component({
  template: '{{ title }}'
})
export class HomeComponent {
  title = $localize`You have 10 users`;
}
```

And

> You have to manually add it to your messages.fr.xlf

```
<trans-unit id="6480943972743237078">
  <source>You have 10 users</source>
  <target>Vous avez 10 utilisateurs</target>
</trans-unit>
```

don't forgot re serve your angular application.

**UPDATE FOR ID**

```
@Component({
  template: '{{ title }}'
})
export class HomeComponent {
  title = $localize`:@@6480943972743237078:`;
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/252966bcca91ea4deb0e52f1f1d0d3f103f84ccd/packages/localize/init/index.ts#L31

Comment: I was able to run with id using the method above. Maybe it might work. @Jimbo

Comment: Yes, that does it.  The problem I'm having now is that it won't read the text from my xlf file.  If I provide text alongside the id that text is used, but changing the translation text in the file has no effect.  Is there something I need to do to update the translation text after changing the file?

Comment: This project helped me use json files as translation resources.
https://github.com/loclapp/locl

Comment: Here's a blog article from Angular on the subject: https://blog.angular.io/angular-localization-with-ivy-4d8becefb6aa

Comment: I tested this in angular 13 and `ng extract-i18n --output-path {your_path}` does generate the trans-unit for $localize inside typescripts.

Answer (score 9):

The better way of translationId is:

```
title = $localize`:@@Home.Title:Some title text`
```

and you have to manually add it to your messages.xx.xlf (for example messages.fr.xlf and so on)

```
<trans-unit id="Home.Title">
  <source>Some title text</source>
  <target>TRANSLATION_HERE</target>
</trans-unit>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some scripts which can be used to extract html + ts side localizations to xlf file. So you use $localize like @Cyclion suggests. This solution uses Ocombe's locl cli package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@locl/cli First you need to build your project without localization.

```
ng build ProjectName --localize=false
```

Then you can extract translations from "binary js"-files using locl tool. I use 0.0.1-beta.6 -version because it doesn't generate target parts in xlf file. Those target parts will ruin merge with xlf-merge. And also ng xi18n tool doesn't generate those target parts as well so structure is consistent after merge.

```
npx locl extract -s='dist/ProjectName/**/*.js' -f=xlf -o='projects/ProjectName/src/locale/messages_extracted.xlf' --locale=fi
```

Then you can combine ng xi18n result and this result. This contains every translations from html and ts but without meta data what ng xi18n command provides from html side translations. I use xlf-merge for this.

```
xlf-merge ./projects/ProjectName/src/locale/messages_extracted.xlf projects/ProjectName/src/locale/messages.xlf -o projects/ProjectName/src/locale/messages.xlf
```

This merge command will add every missing ts side translations to end of messages.xlf-file

Here is whole script.

```
ng xi18n --project=ProjectName --output-path src/locale && ng build ProjectName --localize=false && npx locl extract -s='dist/ProjectName/**/*.js' -f=xlf -o='projects/ProjectName/src/locale/messages_extracted.xlf' --locale=fi && xlf-merge ./projects/ProjectName/src/locale/messages_extracted.xlf projects/ProjectName/src/locale/messages.xlf -o projects/ProjectName/src/locale/messages.xlf
```

And after these steps you have all translation tags in messages.xlf. Then you need to generate/translate each language files using for example xliffmerge tool.

Answer (score 2):

I use [this](https://github.com/mustafah/translations) typescript decorator for translation ! I find it is more productive ...
https://github.com/mustafah/translations