# How to make Angular 9 i18n localization of back-end error codes or typescript component work?

Tags: angular, typescript, localization, internationalization

According to the [official documentation of i18n of Angular](https://angular.io/guide/i18n), I see no way to handle error code coming from back-end to output message to the user based on it. So let's say, the response from back end came as code `2555` which maps to `Maximum size of characters has been reached` in one build of the app (the English one) and maps to `La taille maximale des caractères a été atteinte` in the French build of the app.

- How to achieve this using Angular i18n localization ?
- Is using `$localize` [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60319183/7054574) considered safe for future upgrading ? since I can't find any info about it in the official documentation.

Comment: have you found a solution for this, we are also currently implementing custom error codes for different scenarios and these should be translated and shown to the user

Comment: I temporarily following the old style putting a hidden component with hidden input elements with error codes and translations tags. Now rendering this component could be expensive but it's for one time on the start of the app only so I'm satisfied. I parse these elements in my component (TypeScript part) and get the translation text from them.

Comment: Alternative is using $localize

Comment: Thanks, after some research, we have implemented a map of error codes with matching $localize translations that are matched with the returned errorCode from our Middleware