# Extracting $localize messages from typescript not working in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, localization, internationalization

I thus far know that I can extract i18n messages (from html) by doing `ng xi18n`. But I have also some text in typescript that needs to be translated. I am making use of $localize like this: `$localize':@@info:It's green!'`. If I run `ng xi18n`, it doesn't extract the text with $localize.
I am using Angular 9. Maybe it's a feature that only works in Angular 10? if so, would running the xi18n command do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole new updates are still somewhat undocumented, but for the `ng xi18n` you will need to add `--ivy` for now.

Eventually this should not even use xlf files anymore, but be loaded in `polyfill` as object map (extracting into that form is not automatically done yet though).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried doing `ng xi18n --ivy` but no luck. It does extract a messages.xlf file, but only with i18n that I use in html but still nothing from .ts files. And I get fellowing output message: 
`Ivy extraction not enabled but application is Ivy enabled. If the extraction fails, the `--ivy` flag will enable Ivy extraction.` Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The message says that you should use `--ivy` to enabled ivy extraction (which you just did). In a project of mine I use `ng xi18n --output-path src/locales --out-file source.xlf --ivy ` which works and the xlf contains the nodes for the ts files. I am on cli version 10.1.6 though, so it might that you are on a version that does not support $localize extraction yet.

Comment: It seems like this requires version 10 actually. Topics say they wanted it in 9.x, but seems like it only made it in with 10.

Comment: My bad I should have been more clear about the versions. Yes, the project was made with latest angular cli, so angular 10. And I was trying to extract with a pre-install version (version 9) on my pc. But knowing that I have tried it with angular cli version 10, and it works. But that leaves me with the following question: does this feature of xi18n (extracting typescript files) only works with version 10? if so, is there any alternatieve for angular 9?

Comment: From what I could gather, $localize will need Angular 10 to work with automatic extraction. For static text you could create a component with all the required texts (that isn't actually used somewhere, just as a map). You can also [create this manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60271964/angular-9-i18n-in-typescript) (when values are needed), but that doesn't scale well of course.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue even with angular cli v10. I tried with the `--ivy` option but I got the same issue.
I found a workaround: since only the extraction to xlf files doesn't work but the translation after `build:prod` is well effective even for the `$localize` in the ts files, when I have something to translate which is only in a ts file, I add the words to translate in the html file of the component in a ng-container I never display.
Then it's as usual, when I run the `ng xi18n` I can find the words I need in the xlf file and translate them.

html file:

```
<!-- my regular content -->
<p> this is the regular content of my html file</p>

<!-- The words in my ts files I need to translate with
displayi18n always to "false" so it is never displayed-->
<ng-container *ngIf="displayi18n">
  <span i18n="@@settings">Paramètres</span>
  <span i18n="@@users">Utilisateurs</span>
</ng-container>
```

and in my ts file:

```
@Component ...
export class MyComponent ...
  ...
  // Var to tell ngIf to not display the ng-container for i18n
  public displayi18n: boolean = false;
  
  // Where I need the translated words:
  public settings_label: string = $localize`:@@settings:Paramètres`
  public users_label: string = $localize`:@@users:Utilisateurs`
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As your app is localization enabled (ng add @angular/localize ) then
in your app's angular.json file, you can add  "ivy":true to options under extract-i18n attribute as below:
"extract-i18n": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
"options": {
"browserTarget": "commons-admin:build",
"ivy":true
}
}
Then you will see that i18n-extraction is not only excracting HTML files but also *.ts files which are using $localize format.